# SymmetricDS Split Channel

Tags: symmetricds

After read tutorial. I used MySQL and let say I have 'item_selling_price' table and 'item_selling_price' channel. The row in that table need to mapped to each store. But there is a case when a channel is busy because the traffic to one store.

How to split the channel based on store, so if one channel is busy cannot disturb others to map the row? FYI, MySQL can only has one trigger each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to split the channel. transfer gets blocked on a channel only to one store. not to both. also, no need to declare channel per table. it's enough to have a channel 'master data' from central to stores and 'sales' channel from stores to the central node

Comment: In my experience, there is a case when the channel is busy (because traffic from corp to one store) and no stores can pull the data. So I assume I need to split the channel.

Comment: make the central push the data to the stores. it's better for security also

Comment: how to do that? you mean group link from corp to store is 'P' and also the store to corp? and how can you claim that it's better for security?

Comment: indeed, the group link

Comment: can you please tell me why is it better for security?

Comment: you don't want to open your central DB for remote calls. it's less risky to have it call remote DBs

Comment: how to handle 4k++ datas (and still counting) were processed because push action from corp to (dead/not connected) store?

Comment: nothing. wait until the connection to the store got restored

Comment: oh i see. why push data from central is the solution for busy-stuck channel? and also the channel needs to created based on logical grouping (not only 2 channels for all). http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_channels

Comment: yes, these two groups should be sufficient at least for the beginning

Comment: ah misunderstanding here. My question is for the other problem, not the tutorial one. I just use the tutorial table for explain easily. So how to split the channel?

Comment: no need to split the channel. and you can't split a channel. use multiple channels if needed

Comment: yes, I mean how to use multiple channels in one table if I'm using MySQL? So the other traffic from corp to store cannot be interrupted just because traffic to one store is super busy.

Comment: I need to map almost 10 M rows, and must be delivered independently (if one branch node is busy, it's not prevent other traffic)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111253/discussion-between-boris-pavlovic-and-yosua-lijanto-binar).